# CMake with subdirectories

Tags: c++, build, cmake, directory

I'm trying to set up my project to compile correctly using CMake.

My directory looks like this:

```
root
 |- bin
 |   |- // Where I want to build CMake from - using 'cmake ..'
 |- build
 |   |-
 |- include
 |   |- database
 |   |    |- database.h
 |- src
     |- database
     |    |- database.cpp
     |- main
          |- main.cpp
```

My sub-directories will definitely grow as my project grows larger and figured CMake would probably a good idea to learn. At the moment I can only get CMake to work with no sub-directories inside my src/. However, I do expect this project to grow into many sub-directories.

Would I need multiple **CMakeLists.txt** inside each directory with .cpp files? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: I think CMakeLists.txt is just one and in the parent directory (P.S.) I am not an expert on cmake

Comment: @DanishAlsayed I saw some examples on here and some people were suggesting multiple CMakeLists.txt, however they had a very specific problem and i'm not sure if that's the solution to my problem specifically.

Comment: Did you take a look at the doc? https://cmake.org/examples/

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Your project does not seem to need multiple CMakeLists.txt. The purpose of having multiple CMakeLists.txt multiple times is multi-fold, but it doesn't seem to fit in your project. For example, one benefit would be hierarchical organization, so that you can separate different ***units*** to be built separately, and linked eventually.

**Example**

Consider the situation if you have another directory in your root called `tests`. That directory contains unit tests that you want the developer to have the choice whether to compile it or not. In that case, you put one CMakeLists.txt in `tests`, and you enable this in your primary CMakeLists.txt with a [`add_subdirectory(tests)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_subdirectory.html) as so:

```
if(testing_enabled)
    add_subdirectory(tests)
endif()
```

In `tests`, there would be another CMakeLists.txt. This way, you separate concerns. The development of your unit tests is independent of the development of your project, and also the build process is separate.

**Another example**

Consider the situation if you have two libraries where the user can choose from. In this case, you have in your `root` two directories, `lib1` and `lib2`. Now you can do something like this in your primary CMakeLists.txt:

```
if(IWantLib1)
    add_subdirectory(lib1)
else()
    add_subdirectory(lib2)
endif()
```

And both `lib1` and `lib2` directories contain CMakeLists.txt.

Answer (score 84):

I'll refer you to [this article](https://crascit.com/2016/01/31/enhanced-source-file-handling-with-target_sources/) for an in-depth discussion of the two main approaches, but there's a few ways you could structure a project such as this.

- One `CMakeLists.txt` file at the top level which lists all the source files out in all the different subdirectories. You typically only see this for very simple projects.
- One `CMakeLists.txt` file in each directory, each one brought in by its parent using `add_subdirectory()`. This approach is very common and is usually the recommended one.
- One `CMakeLists.txt` file at the top level, each subdirectory having its own file that lists its own source files and targets. The top level `CMakeLists.txt` file brings in the subdirectory files with `include()`. This method is less common, but can have advantages over the other two in some circumstances. Not the recommended approach in general though.

Each has its pros and cons. Having just one top level `CMakeLists.txt` file would only be recommended if there were very few files and subdirectories. Once the project grows, keeping everything in the top level can become too much and make the resultant `CMakeLists.txt` file harder to follow. It also has the disadvantage that a change for a file addition or removal isn't restricted to a particular directory. That may not seem like a big deal, but if multiple people are working on a project and you want to easily see what part of a project someone else's changes affect (e.g. in a git history), it is harder. This is especially true if you both add/remove a file, thereby both change the top level `CMakeLists.txt` file and have the possibility of a conflict.

Once a project becomes non-trivial in size, most choose to add a `CMakeLists.txt` file in each subdirectory and use `add_subdirectory()` to bring them all together. @TheQuantumPhysicist's answer gives a good example of how this can be useful, so I won't repeat most of those details here. This structure offers you the ability to turn on/off whole sections of the build tree easily, but more importantly it gives each subdirectory its own variable scope. This can be important if you want to set variables, etc. in one part of the source tree but not have those changes visible in another part. Each subdirectory also gets its own directory property scope. These separate scopes make it easier to apply things like compiler flags and other temporary values to just one section of a complex directory structure.

The third option of one top level `CMakeLists.txt` file with each subdirectory providing a file brought in by `include()` is less common, but it has similarities to using one `CMakeLists.txt` file in each subdirectory. Both localise details about files in a directory to a `CMakeLists.txt` or other similarly named file in just that directory. Changes therefore become easier to merge and to understand in version control histories, etc. When using CMake 3.12 or earlier, one thing that this third approach allows which the second doesn't is you can use `target_link_libraries()` a bit more freely when using `target_sources()` to specify the source files in each subdirectory. The article linked at the top of this answer goes into detail about why `target_sources()` can be advantageous. If your minimum CMake version is 3.13 or later though, the third approach is inferior to the second and should be avoided in general.

Lastly, I'd suggest you don't pick up the habit of putting your build tree inside your source tree. Rather, create your build tree(s) as siblings of the source tree. Aim to keep your source tree untouched by a build. All it takes is to have someone create a directory in the source tree with the same name as whatever you've used for the build tree for things to go awry (I've seen this more than once!). You may also want to set up multiple build trees for the one source tree, such as one for a Debug build and another as a Release build, so having these outside the source tree also helps keep your source tree less cluttered.

Comment: Great advice, thank you very much. On your last point, I made a typo. I meant to place that comment on the build line.. I won't build from the bin directory. I imagine the build directory is where I want to invoke CMake?

Comment: Yes, I already assumed you meant that you were running CMake in the `build` directory rather than `bin`. The usual way is to run CMake from the build directory. It is possible to run CMake from anywhere and still use a specific directory as the build directory using the undocumented `-B` option, but I wouldn't recommend you do that unless there is a good reason.

Comment: The article you linked at the top seems not to load any more.  Here is an archive from October 2023 in case it helps someone else looking for the blog: https://web.archive.org/web/20231003213207/https://crascit.com/2016/01/31/enhanced-source-file-handling-with-target_sources/

Comment: There may have been a brief outage when you tried to reach it. The link still works for me now.