# ns3 running failure due to CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake, c++17, ubuntu-22.04, ns-3

I have begun to make a network simulation using ns-3.39.
However, after installation, I met a problem to run a simulation.
When I try to run first.cc in the tutorial folder, the terminal displays:

```
./first.cc: line 1: /bin: Is a directory
./first.cc: line 2: CMakeLists.txt: command not found
...
./first.cc: line 11: CMakeLists.txt: command not found
./first.cc: line 31: syntax error near unexpected token '"FirstScriptExample"'
./first.cc: line 31: 'NS_LOG_COMPONENT_DEFINE("FirstScriptExample");'
```

and then expires the code.

I checked every folder of ns3 but there exists 'CMakeLists.txt' file in the every folder.
And I followed the process to 4.3.2 in the link below:
https://www.nsnam.org/docs/manual/html/working-with-cmake.html

But nothing changed.

Comment: how are you running `first.cc`?

Comment: I run the file using terminal. Speciffically, I run the file by these commands:

```cd ./ns-allinone-3.39/ns-3.39/examples/tutorial
./first.cc```

Comment: @PSH It's a C++ source code, you shouldn't run it directly. ".cc" one of the C++ source file extension like ".cpp" or ".cxx".

Comment: you need to run cmake, build the resulting project then run the executable, see the instructions in the webpage you linked to

Answer (score 2):

The "ns-allinone-3.39/ns-3.39/examples/tutorial/first.cc" you mentioned is C++ source code, not a script or executable, so you can't run it directly in terminal.

C++ source code can end with many kinds of extension, e.g. `.cpp`, `.cc`, `.cxx` ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546107/19647418)), and header end with `.h`, `.hpp`, etc. They are just text files and have to be compile to binary before you run it.

### Install from apt

If you just want to use the program.

- Run `sudo apt install ns3` to install.
- Run `dpkg -L ns3` to see what do the package installed, usually the executable is installed under "/usr/bin".

### Build from source

If you want to build it from source:

1. configure (follow [tutorial](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/manual/html/working-with-cmake.html) 4.3.1.1.)

- cd to "ns-allinone-3.39/ns-3.39" and run

> `./ns3 configure -d release --enable-examples --enable-tests`

This step create "cmake-cache" and "build" directory.

2. build (found on "ns-allinone-3.39/ns-3.39/README.md")

```
./ns3
```

The examples are now living in the "ns-allinone-3.39/ns-3.39/build/examples".

### Note

- Many CMakeLists.txt: The developer put CMakeLists.txt in many directory is a common approach, check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42753501/19647418).
- In Linux, usually executable have no extensions, and usually shell script have no extension or ".sh". (check the [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/174356) for more information)

Comment: Just an addend `./ns3 run first.cc` will build and run the first.cc example.

Running `./ns3` after configuring will build the entire simulator (plus examples and tests if --enable-examples and --enable-tests are set), which might be pretty slow depending on the computer.